# Multiple images not showing in frontend virtuemart2?

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I am using Joomla 2.5.8 and virtue mart 2.0.14,I uploaded multiple images to a product in virtue mart but it displays only single images instead of displaying multiple images.How can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question but once something similar happened to me - I uploaded more photos of a product but when I looked at its detail on the front-end, there was just one image. The silly reason for it was that I was looking at another product than I added additional images for.

However, I would strongly recommend you looking at the Joomla Extensions and download a plugin for it.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions